# Distinction between PROCEDURE and CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE in Toad and Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I'm learning Oracle, PL/SQL, and Toad.  As I understand it, a procedure likely begins with:
PROCEDURE my_procedure IS
BEGIN...

I have created procedures in Toad, and it always makes this:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure IS
/****(boilerplate comments)
BEGIN...

It works fine.  I paste in my DML SQL, execute it, refresh my Schema browser, and my_procedure is there.  If I execute my_procedure using Toad, my data is modified as expected.  I could just leave it alone.  But I don't understand why I'm CREATE OR REPLACE-ing my PROCEDURE every time when I have finished writing it and just want to run the DML.  The goal is to have a simple procedure that my colleague can call from one of his Perl scripts, or any other means that might be needed in the future.

If I open it in Toad's editor and delete the "CREATE OR REPLACE" and just leave PROCEDURE, I get an Invalid SQL Syntax error.

Comment: What is the question here? Do you want to know that yes, if you want to create an object, be it a table, a view, a sequence, a function, ... or a procedure, in SQL, you need to use an appropriate `CREATE` statement, that begins with, well, with `CREATE`?

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks as if you don't understand how it works.

In order to **create** a procedure, in **any tool** (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD, ...) you have to use appropriate syntax which is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc AS ...
```

For example:

```
SQL> create procedure my_proc as
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

In order to **run** (execute) it, you'd call it as

```
SQL> begin
  2    my_proc;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So far so good. Though, this procedure doesn't do anything at all, so if you want to **edit** its code, you'd try to "reuse" a script you already have (the `create procedure ...` one):

```
SQL> create procedure my_proc as
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*) into l_cnt from dual;
  5  end;
  6  /
create procedure my_proc as
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Whooops! `my_proc` already exists! So, what should I do?

- one option is to drop it first, then create it back:

  ```
  SQL> drop procedure my_proc;

  Procedure dropped.

  SQL> create procedure my_proc as
    2    l_cnt number;
    3  begin
    4    select count(*) into l_cnt from dual;
    5  end;
    6  /

  Procedure created.
  ```
- another (which we *usually* use) is to use `create or replace` option:

  ```
  SQL> create or replace procedure my_proc as
    2    l_cnt number;
    3  begin
    4    select count(*) into l_cnt from dual;
    5  end;
    6  /

  Procedure created.
  ```

Of course, you still use it the same way as previously:

```
SQL> begin
  2    my_proc;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now, suppose you all (you and your colleagues) went to sleep and tomorrow morning someone wants to run the procedure. No problem - they would use the same code I posted last:

```
SQL> begin
  2    my_proc;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It means that **you** don't have to `create or replace` the procedure again - it is stored in the database, waiting to be called. Unless something happened - which would "break it" (make it invalid) - you don't have to touch (recreate) the procedure ever again. If you do, you know the drill: `create or replace procedure my_proc as ...`

Therefore: what you said & what bothers you:

> But I don't understand why I'm CREATE OR REPLACE-ing my PROCEDURE every time when I have finished writing it and just want to run the DML.

is simply **wrong**. You don't have to `create or replace` the procedure every time. You just use it.

Answer (score 0):

When any object (procedure or function..) is created for the first time "Create Procedure XXX.." is sufficient but in order to edit the existing procedure we need to mention "Create or Replace..". Thus, Oracle understands you are going to edit the existing object.

Coming to your question, Toad and Sql-Developers are tools, thus when you create the Procedure and click that procedure name from the procedure section in GUI, it will take you to editable code. Thus, it by default changes the "Create Procedure.." to "Create or Replace .."

Run the following query and see the metadata (Text Column) of your procedure. It will not have "Craete or Replace.."

```
 select * from all_source where owner='SCHEMA NAME' and TYPE='PROCEDURE';
```

Comment: As you say, in the TYPE column, there's just PROCEDURE my_procedure IS. I suppose, then, that when someone calls my_procedure from a Perl script, or perhaps an APEX page, they are not executing a CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE, but just the contents of my_procedure, even though I always see CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE in a Toad editor.

Comment: It seems you are confusing with the syntaxes, see the @littlefoot explanation. 
If you observe, when you created a new procedure you wrote code as "Create xx Procedure IS..". But, when you did the above query it does not have the "Create" part in it. Why?. Because we instructed Oracle to create a procedure it did and saved it in its source, thus only "Procedure XX IS..". So, any applications calling it (Apex/Perl) will see the "Procedure XX IS.. ".

Comment: As said, when you use coding tools like Toad/SQL-Developer to see a procedure in GUI it takes the user to an editable page or makes the format easy to export. That's why you are seeing the "Create or Replace Procedure my_procedure IS.."
All in all, if the procedure is working as intended, you are good.